# How can I change the user icon in Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, icons

I have more than one user in Chrome Browser (**chrome://settings/** *Add new user*) and can't find out how to specify a custom icon for each user. Chrome allow me select an icon from a list of icons set, but I want set my own image.

Comment: @David That doesn't matter. What matters is how the question is perceived; if there is a later duplicate question that has been better recieved, then the earlier question is considered a duplicate of the later one. For that reason, you are indeed correct that this question is duplicate, and the question has since attracted answers correct for the current version of Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start Chrome using a specified "user profile"?](http://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile)

Comment: @cybermonkey not duplicate at all. This question is about changing user icon. The other is about choosing profile.

Comment: It was not previously possible (at least, not easily). It is now. See (and upvote) answer posted here: https://superuser.com/a/1020694/27017

Comment: Right answer now is below: https://superuser.com/a/1429998/194248

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Google Chrome OS**

If you are talking about changing a user account picture on Chrome OS (Google's operating system), a simple search will find that information for you on [Google's Help site](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1059258). Below is from the previous link.

> **Change your account picture**
>
> 1. If you haven’t already, sign in to your Chrome device.
> 2. Click the status area in the lower-right corner, where your account picture
>      appears.
> 3. Select Settings and find the “Users” section.
> 4. Click the
>      picture for your account. In the “Change picture” dialog that appears,
>      you can reset your account picture:
>
>    - Choose a file: Click the  icon to
>        use an image saved on your Chrome device or a connected external
>        device.
>    - Take a photo: Click the  icon to take a new snapshot using a
>        webcam. Strike your favorite pose, then click the  button. To flip
>        your photo horizontally, place your cursor over the photo and click on
>        the arrow icon in the lower-right. If you're dissatisfied with the
>        photo, click the  button to retake it, as many times as you like!
>    - Use
>        your Google Profile photo: Use the same photo associated with the
>        public profile for your Google Account. Learn more about Google
>        Profiles.
>    - Use an icon: Do you think puppies are cute? Are you an avid
>        cyclist? Choose from a variety of fun icons.

**Google Chrome Browser**

To change an account picture on Google Chrome (the browser), follow the directions below:

1. login as the user you want to change the picture for.
2. Left-click on the icon of the user in the top-left corner.
3. Hover your mouse over the account you would like to change the picture for and click "Edit".
4. From the "Edit user" menu, you can change the name, add/remove a desktop shortcut, and change the picture associated with the user account.

At this time it is not possible to use your own custom picture in Google Chrome, but it is possible to use your own custom picture in Chromium as per [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91230) link. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/413145/can-i-change-the-icon-used-to-identify-profiles-in-google-chrome-web-browser) Superuser question asked the same question, but at the time, the answer was "no". Now the answer is "yes", but only for Chromium.

Comment: The Google Chrome instructions appear to not work anymore (at least for me on a Mac). Sxc's answer worked though: https://superuser.com/a/1370984/2647

Answer (score 32):

one of my google account lost the Avator chosen and become default gray anonymous icons

Seems the behavior changed on version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

1. Select the google profile you want to configure (if you have more than one Google Chrome profile)
2. Click "three dots" located on the top right-hand corner
3. Choose **Settings**
4. Click **You and Google**
5. Click **Chrome name and picture**
6. You will then see the screen for choosing your Avatar (as the screen provided by @serge-k 's answer)

Other ways to find the **change picture** page:

- Just go to chrome://settings/manageProfile chrome://settings/manageProfile
- Or you can search in settings for "chrome picture"

Comment: I had a photo from the Gmail account, shown as the profile avatar ( that Chrome calls a "person"), I've switched to an example picture given in the settings by Chrome, and now, it's impossible to get back the Gmail account picture! How to do that?

Comment: I just tried, it show me the one linked with Chrome, just like the one beside my @Sxc  
Are your chrome in sync with Google yet?

Comment: Not in sync, it's probably the problem, I'll have to test. If it's the case, that's really painful to be forced to sync for this.

Comment: I can get to "Chrome name and picture" but all I see is a grid of default cartoonish pictures and my first initial in a coloured circle. Don't see any option to set a custom picture here.

Comment: Same thing, there's no custom picture anymore (v85 right now). The only way I could get a custom picture is to sing in with a gmail account.

Answer (score 18):

Go to this folder:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Avatars
```

Replace the file `avatar_secret_agent.png` (or the name of your Avatar) with your custom photo. Make sure the name and extension both match.

[image: Screen shot from my chrome]

Comment: This works, but it only changes the image shown in the profile menu. It does not change the desktop icon or add the new image as an icon option (when creating another profile). You could easily lose the change by selecting this icon again (causing the file to be overwritten). I also suspect that if you use the same icon for two profiles, both profiles will see the change.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... Several of my chrome icons are a big "M" in various shades of the same color that was apparently pulled from my Google account.

Comment: This directory `Google\Chrome\User Data` (or at least, the Mac equivalent) doesn't seem to exist anymore in Chrome 87.

Comment: ...however it does seem to work (with caveats in other comments above) in `Google\Chrome\Avatars` -- e.g. on my Mac it's `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Avatars`

Answer (score 7):

**Chrome Browser, Version 46.0.2490.86 m**

Chrome will detect your general Google account picture and import it as the first image in the icon line up.  See below...

[image]

However, if you didn't have this image already set when you "added" your account, then you will have to simply "remove" your account and add it back in.  Obviously, if you don't have a general Google account picture set, then there is nothing to grab and you must create it, first.

What is meant by general Google account picture, i.e. the picture associated with your e-mail, Google+, etc.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: That's the one!

Answer (score 3):

```
chrome://flags/#enable-new-profile-management
```

Set this to 'enabled' and relaunch Chrome. That will bring the new right-corner username menu with name instead of image. However currently going back to the same address and setting that to 'disabled', then relaunching, will show the Google account user image instead of the avatar, or that image will become available among the avatar images.

(It's like a bug: going directly from 'default to 'disabled' will not work. You have to go from default to enabled, relaunch and then disable and relaunch.)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/879358/162573

Comment: Not working in Chrome 54

Comment: This option doesn't exist anymore, as I think they all switched to the new way to manage profile.

Answer (score 3):

Once the image is in place there seems no way to change it with a different custom image. FRUSTRATING!

However, on a Mac, navigate to `Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` and place your new custom image there and then change the name of it to "Google Profile Picture". My old one was a `.png` so I kept the new one as a `.png` as well.

Relaunch Chrome and witness the change in the top right User menu. Regarding the old image, rename it with a different character in front so it's not used but you can switch back if the new one's size is wonky.

Comment: For windows, the location is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`. Also see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/639258/10342) for how to hack in custom image without need to have google login (using same mechanism though)

Comment: Perfect. Note that if you have multiple profiles, the folder will be `Profile 2`, `Profile 3`, etc. instead of `Default`.

Comment: doesn't seem to be used anymore nowadays: there is no /Library/Application Support/Google as of OS X 10.15 (Catalina) and Chrome 87.

Comment: oh -- you mean ~/Library/Application Support/Google -- very important difference.

Comment: One upvote, but you're my hero for today -- this issue has been bothering me for years!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.
Go here:

```
chrome://settings/people
```

Look for "Chrome name and picture"
Click and edit.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to change your profile picture in Google account settings. After that, turn off the sync and then turn on again. You will see the updated icon on the top right side.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome updates it's local icon automatically, after you set an image for your Google / GMAIL account using the help already provided in these answers.

You may need to sign out then sign back into your google account in Chrome (not delete the user profile, just sign out and in) to get the online Google image to update to your local computer.

Answer (score 1):

**2019 Update** (Chrome 73 at the time of this post)

For Chrome browser profiles not associated with a Gmail account, it has become fairly simple to add a custom avatar.

1. On the new tab (or [Google search](https://www.google.com/)) page, click the *user profile icon* at upper right, which is typically a circle containing the user's first initial.
2. Click the blue *Google Account* button.
3. Click *Personal info* in the left sidebar.
4. Again click the user profile circle, then upload or select a photo.

Comment: this answer is for profiles **associated with**; the text says **not associated with**.

Comment: Yes but your answer is incorrect; you should change "not associated with" to "associated with".

Answer (score 1):

Change Chrome Browser Profile Picture **WITHOUT** Signing Into Google Account

1. Using a file explorer, go to C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\
2. Rename the Avatars file to Avatars2
3. Create a new Avatars directory
4. Copy one of the avatars (e.g., avatar_illustration_cheese.png) from Avatars2 to the new Avatars directory
5. Rename that avatar with a 2 after the .png (e.g., avatar_illustration_cheese.png2)
6. To change the avatar to a different color, white for example, open that image in a photo editor and change the color
7. Save that image with the same name but without the 2 (e.g., avatar_illustration_cheese.png)
8. To change the avatar to a picture, open any photo in an editor, change the size to 192x192, and rename it to the same name as the file saved in step 4 and save it to the new Avatar directory
9. Restart the browser and the new image will show as the profile icon

Answer (score 0):

```
In Chrome 78 (windows) 
click on account picture at extreme right. 
Click on **Addresses and More**
At left side click on **People**. In first tab Select **Chrome and Picture**. 
Now Select your picture/icon and update name and press back arrow.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First click the upper right picture on chrome
2. Click on manage account
3. Click on this picture:

[image: pic]

4. Select an image from your device
5. Then re-login to your Google account in Chrome
6. The picture will be changed

Comment: Welcome Ahmed!  Can you please edit your answer to fix the formatting, make the image visible, and add an image description to help the visually impaired?  Thanks!